# $.post POST 404 (Not Found)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, post

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this 404 error?  I'm using Spring MVC as the backend, using jQuery's $.post to send a POST request.

The code is running from a WAR file hosted on the server I'm trying to POST to.

Spring Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postTesting(@RequestParam(value = "message", required = false) String message) {
    logger.info("POST Testing");
    return message;
}
```

jQuery POST code:

```
$("#testButton").on('click', function() {
    $.post('http://tylernoip.ddns.net/Pear/testing', {message: "Hello POST!"}, function(returnedData) {
        $("#outputDiv").append(returnedData);
    });
});
```

And here is the error from the console:

[image]

Also notice the URL; I'm posting to the same URL that I have open - why is it not being found?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: 404 - the resource cannot be found. You're getting the error because whatever it is you're looking for is not at that location. Use the correct URL or ensure that your required resource is in the correct place.

Comment: That's what is confusing me, is as you can see the URL and the $.post request are matching up.

Comment: I took another look. Your URL and $.post request do not match. You have `Pear` in one but `pear` in the other. Depending on the server platform, URLs can be case sensitive. Visiting the version with `Pear` returns a small HTML page.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Sorry about that, I originally had uppercase Pear when I was testing it, and switched it to lowercase to try something new.  I have replaced the picture in the original question to reflect the problem more accurately.  As you can see, the URLs do match (now), yet I still get a 404 error :(.  Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like this has something to do with the request method at this point. Perhaps this is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067563/spring-controller-404-retuned-after-post-method-invoked

Comment: That was exactly it!  I needed to add an `@ResponseBody` annotation above my method, below my `@RequestMethod` annotation.  If you want to submit it is an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will answer it.